# Unable to install LWC in PC and getting port error

Tags: lightning-web-components

Starting SFDX: Authorize a Dev Hub

> 01:55:59.676 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername
>   ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  Cannot start the OAuth redirect
>   server on port PortInUseAction.

Try this: 
Kill the process running on port 1717 or use a custom connected app and update OauthLocalPort in the sfdx-project.json file.
01:56:01.7 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername ended with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://someurl.salesforce.com",
  "oauthLocalPort": 3000, // <--- this
  "sourceApiVersion": "46.0"
}
```

in your sfdx-project.json to change the oAuth local port